# In one tomcat, project wise memory

Tags: java, tomcat

how i can give specific amount of memory to my web application,i deployed more than one project in single instance of tomcat ,i want to allocate memory to my each web application specific amount of memory

set "CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
set "CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -DT247ApiAnalytics.heap.size=512m"

i tried this command to set in setenv.bat file catalina.bat file but i want to start my tocat as a window services not from the bat file  and i want it for permanet is there any way to allocate specific amount of memory to my each web application deployed on single instance of tomcat. its working but it setting the jvm memoty not web application memory ,i want to set the specific amount of memory ,

also this command too
set "CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m" && [ "$APP_NAME" == "<Project_Name>" ] && CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dapp.name=<Project_Name>"

but this also not worked for me .if u have any solution please help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I depolyee two project [application] in one Tomcat
Tomcat's memory is 4 gb.
I want to give specific memory to one project [application] 
For example : 
1 application with 1 gb memory
and 
2 application with 3 gb memory
what should i do regarding same ?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no such option *within a single process*. All webapplications share the memory that is allocated to their common JVM.

There is an option to start multiple processes from the same installation - `CATALINA_HOME` vs `CATALINA_BASE` are the configuration options from the command line, and you can also install with different service-names (if I'm not misremembering) and configure the individual services to deploy different web applications.

Comment: thank you for answering ,is it possible somehow i can do that ? any lead towards it ?

Comment: ...possible that you do what? What you've asked in your original question: No. As I answered. What I suggested instead: Yes, as I answered. And, IMHO, the steps to do that are also contained in the answer.